# Remove XML duplicate items in Excel using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have 10 Excel sheets each I've loaded with different XML feed connections.
So, In order to get followed those 10 list updates regularly I used XML append data!

But the problem here is, that feed is giving duplicate items each time I XML table refresh.

Now, I want a VBA code remove all those duplicate items in all sheets at once.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Macro_Table()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xmltable As LisObject

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.worksheets
        Set xmltable = ws.ListObjects(1)
        xmltable.Range().RemoveDuplicate Columns:=Array(4), Headers:= Yes
    Next ws
End Sub
```

But when running this - the following error is coming:

> Sub script out of range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the error is that you hit a Worksheet that doesn't contain a `ListObjects(1)`. The reason it has to be on that line is because the line underneath it won't compile at all:

```
xmltable.Range().RemoveDuplicate Columns:=Array(4), Headers:= Yes
```

...should look more like this:

```
xmltable.Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4), Header:=xlYes
```

You need to remove the parentheses from the .Range() call unless you are referencing a sub-range.  "Headers:=" is not an argument name, it should be "Header:=", and you need to use the enumeration xlYes instead of the undefined value "Yes".  Finally, `RemoveDuplicate` should be `RemoveDuplicates`.

If you don't have `Option Explicit` on, Yes will be a new Variant, get assigned a default value of 0, and be passed to the function as basically `xlGuess`.

You should also correct your variable declaration, `Dim xmltable As ListObject` instead of `LisObject`.

Put it back together with a check to see if the ListObject exists, and you get something like this:

```
Sub Macro_Table()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xmltable As ListObject

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.ListObjects.Count <> 0 Then
            Set xmltable = ws.ListObjects(1)
            xmltable.Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4), Header:=xlYes
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub
```